# Jenkins: Unable to access jarfile remoting.jar

Tags: windows, ssh, java, jenkins, jar

I am have a Jenkins setup, where Controller (linux) is connected to slave (windows) via ssh using username/password authentication. I am whenever I try to launch the agent I get `Error: Unable to access jarfile remoting.jar`. I have tried modifying the file and folder permissions, but that didn't seen to fix the issue. What is causing jenkins to not be able to access or execute the jarfile?

"Remote Root Directory" is set to `D:\Jenkins1114`, Default Shell is `cmd.exe`, Java version on slave is `11.0.11`, Java version on Controller is `11.0.13`

Relevant logs:

```
[12/28/21 15:37:40] [SSH] Starting agent process: cd "D:\Jenkins1114" && java  -jar remoting.jar -workDir D:\Jenkins1114 -jar-cache D:\Jenkins1114/remoting/jarCache
Error: Unable to access jarfile remoting.jar
Agent JVM has terminated. Exit code=1
[12/28/21 15:37:41] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[12/28/21 15:37:41] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

Answer (score 1):

It fails because cd "D:\Jenkins1114" doesn't actually change the drive.  The command needs to be

cd /d "D:\Jenkins1114"

As such it doesn't find the jar file because after the cd it's still on the C: drive not the D: drive.  Sorry I've not found a solution other than only install jenkins on the C: drive.